# Google Dynamic Search Ads (DSA) pull landing / exit page specific data from API

Tags: google, api, google-search-ads-360

We build a tool which links onsite visitor data and google Ads data.
For the non-DSA ads we get specific information which we can link to the unique visitor.
FOr some reason google Ads seem to only sent totals for the DSA campaigns.
Is there an option we are missing or is it impossible to link information from DSA campaigns to specific user, as is the case with the other ads?

Comment: What information are you trying to link? If you're trying to pass keyword data over, you can't. You *should* (AFAIK) be able to pass campaign, ad group, and search query data.

Comment: What we actually need is information of costs per landingpage for the DSA campaigns, since we want to be able to see the ad-costs and ad-profits per landingpage.
We currently only receive costs per DSA campaign, but the DSA campaigns use multple landingpages.

Comment: Do you have your Google Ads account properly linked to Analytics and have you turned on autotagging? Because you can then just get that data from Analytics.

Comment: I would like to know the specific landing page and cost per click for DSA campaigns. I dont understand how I should be able to get these using analytics. Can you please elaborate?